# How to handle InterruptedException of BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

I have a code similar to this which is inside `run()` method of a `Runnable` and multiple instances of that `Runnable` get launched,

```
do{
        try{
            String contractNum=contractNums.take();
           }catch(InterruptedException e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
  }while(!("*".equals(contractNum)));
```

Where `contractNums` is a `BlockingQueue<String>` shared by multiple threads. There are separate `Runnables` putting elements to this queue.

I am not sure about next steps after catching `InterruptedException`, should I terminate this thread by re throwing a `RuntimeException` ( so my `while` loop terminates ) or try to take next element from `contractNum queue` again and ignoring `InterruptedException`?

I am not sure if `InterruptedException` to be treated as a fatal condition for thread to terminate or keep it in while loop.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Are there places where you intentionally interrupt the thread, for example to tell it to finish up (for example during shutdown)? If not, you just need to handle possible spurious interrupts that will wake up the thread. If you don't want the processing to be affected, just ignore them. They're in absolutely no way *fatal* exceptions, and you don't need to log them (especially as errors).

Comment: Thanks. No, there are no intentional interrupts.

Comment: Then you don't need to take any special action on them.

Answer (score 4):

**7.1.2 Interruption policies**

> Just as tasks should have a cancellation policy, threads should have
>   an interruption policy. An interruption policy determines how a thread
>   interprets an interruption request—what it does (if anything) when one
>   is detected, what units of work are considered atomic with respect to
>   interruption, and how quickly it reacts to interruption. The most
>   sensible interruption policy is some form of thread-level or service-
>   level cancellation: exit as quickly as practical, cleaning up if
>   necessary, and pos- sibly notifying some owning entity that the thread
>   is exiting. It is possible to establish other interruption policies,
>   such as pausing or resuming a service, but threads or thread pools
>   with nonstandard interruption policies may need to be restricted to
>   tasks that have been written with an awareness of the policy.

**7.1.3 Responding to interruption**

> As mentioned befor, when you call an interruptible blocking method
>   such as Thread.sleep or BlockingQueue.put , there are two practical
>   strategies for handling InterruptedException :
>
> • Propagate the exception (possibly after some task-specific cleanup),
>   making your method an interruptible blocking method, too; or
>
> • Restore the interruption status so that code higher up on the call
>   stack can deal with it.

[Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)  Chapter 7.

Specifically in your code you will need to make sure that if thread is interrupted your application logic is not broken. 
And it is indeed better to catch your interruption exception. What to with it is up to you just try to make sure that you don't break the application logic.

Comment: Thanks for quoting that book. On page 143 - 144 , my scenario is described and suggests that I need to call , `Thread.currentThread.interrupt()` only once in an outer `finally` block when thread is about to finish - irrespective of number of times this exception is thrown. In inner catch, I should ignore exception and retry to `take()` elements from queue.